# Django Login/authenticate user not sticking around

Tags: django, authentication

I've been trying to implement a simple login/logout/signup system for my Django project, but the login doesn't seem to have any effect or stick around when the user change pages (in other words, request.user.is_authenticated is False if I go from the login page to the user, home or credit page or any other page). I have another project with a similar code and it works, so I'm really lost. The Authenticate doesn't work either, so I have a manual one.

Views.py

```
def userCreate(request):
    """
    Creating a new user
    """
    user=User()
    
    user_form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=user) 
    if user_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        if user is not None:  
            login(request, user)
        return redirect('user_home', user_id=user.id) 

    return render(request, 'lognom/user_create.html', {'user_form':user_form}) 
    
def userLogIn(request):
    LogInForm_form = LogInForm(request.POST or None)
    if LogInForm_form.is_valid():
        email_field = LogInForm_form.cleaned_data['login_email']
        password_field = LogInForm_form.cleaned_data['login_password']
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(user_email=email_field)
        except:
            error="Invalid user email or password"
            return render(request, 'lognom/login.html', {'LogInForm_form':LogInForm_form, 'error':error})
        if user.password == password_field:
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('user_home', user_id=user.id)
            else:
                error="Invalid user email or password"
                return render(request, 'lognom/login.html', {'LogInForm_form':LogInForm_form, 'error':error})
    return render(request, 'lognom/login.html', {'LogInForm_form':LogInForm_form})
    
def userLogOut(request):
    """
    Log out
    """
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'lognom/logout.html')
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    '''
    This table is the User table. Signing up/in uses email and password.
    '''
    ## This field contains the name of the User
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    
## This field contains the first name of the User
    user_firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    
    ## This field contains the title of the User
    user_title=models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    
    ## This field contains the password of the User 
    password=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    
    ## This field contains the email of the User
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False)
    
    ## This field contains the sign up date of the user 
    user_sign_up_date=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    
    ## This field contains the institution of the user 
    user_institution=models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD='user_email'
    PASSWORD_FIELD='password'
   
    def checkuser(self):
        return (User.get_username(self))
        
    objects=UserManager()   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        ordering = ['user_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_firstname+" "+self.user_name
```

If I force a login on a given page (e.g. the user page, like this:

```
def userHome(request, user_id):
    
    user=User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    login(request, user)
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    print(request.user)
```

), it does answer True and the name of the user, but the authentification will not stick around if I go to the general home page.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the authentication part, the right way to authenticate and login the user with your code is:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login 


def userLogIn(request):
    LogInForm_form = LogInForm(request.POST or None)
    if LogInForm_form.is_valid():
        email_field = LogInForm_form.cleaned_data['login_email']
        password_field = LogInForm_form.cleaned_data['login_password']
        # HERE is where you validate and authenticate the user
        user = authenticate(
            request, 
            email=email_field, 
            password=password_field
        )
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
            return redirect('user_home', user_id=user.id)
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            error = "Invalid user email or password"
            return render(request, 'lognom/login.html', {'LogInForm_form': LogInForm_form, 'error': error})
    return render(request, 'lognom/login.html', {'LogInForm_form': LogInForm_form})
```

Comment: Sadly, the issue doesn't seem to be with the Authenticate part. I think for that part that something is missing in the Model for the password, and that's why authenticate() doesn't work as it should, but login() also fails if I force directly a given user. See the last part of my question.